# Solving linear system using matrix exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $\vec{x}^\prime=\begin{pmatrix} 2& 1\\1&2\\\end{pmatrix}x$ with initial condition $\vec{x}(0)=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\-2\\\end{pmatrix}$

So I'm trying to find the matrix exponential

I want to use that $e^At=e^{Bt+Ct}$ since the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0\\0&2\\\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1\\1&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ commute.

The matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0\\0&2\\\end{pmatrix}=2I$

So I have $e^{Bt}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}2^kI^k=\begin{pmatrix} e^{2t}& 0\\0&e^{2t}\\\end{pmatrix}$

But for the matrix $C$, I have $C^2=I$

So $e^{Ct}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}C^k=I+Ct+\frac{t^2}{2}I+....$

So I think I have $\begin{pmatrix} e^t& 0\\0& e^t\\\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} t& 0\\0& t\\\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0& t\\t& 0\\\end{pmatrix}$

So do I have $e^{Ct}=\begin{pmatrix} e^t-t& t\\t& e^t-t\\\end{pmatrix}$

Then I get $e^{At}=\begin{pmatrix} e^{2t}& 0\\0&e^{2t}\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} e^t-t& t\\t& e^t-t\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} e^{2t}(e^t-t)& te^{2t}\\te^{2t}& e^{2t}(e^t-t)\\\end{pmatrix}$

And then I use $\vec{x}(t)=e^{At}\vec{x}_0=\begin{pmatrix} e^{2t}(e^t-t)& te^{2t}\\te^{2t}& e^{2t}(e^t-t)\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3\\-2\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3e^{2t}(e^t-t)-2te^{2t}\\3te^{2t}-2e^{2t}(e^t-t)\\\end{pmatrix}$

I'm assuming my exponential matrix is wrong.

Comment: You’re correct: the exponential is wrong. The second matrix is a reflection, so its eigenvalues are $\pm1$. You’re probably better off just computing the eigenvalues of the original matrix, which can be done by inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to take more terms of the power series to see the pattern for the result. As $C^2=I$, so is $C^3=C$ and in general $C^{2k}=I$ and $C^{2k+1}=C$. This splits the exponential series in even and odd part. The even and odd part of the exponential are the hyperbolic cosine and sine. Thus
$$
\exp(Ct)=\cosh(t)I+\sinh(t)C.
$$